# Is it just me, or is this trick-ramp broken?

Tags: mario-kart-8

This is the first Tri-Fire Bar in Bowser's Castle:

[image: image of relevant place]

When I'm on the right side of this ramp (offscreen), I can trick off it without a problem. But here, on the left side, it just doesn't seem to work; I just hop off the ramp with no trick. Is this problem on my end, or is the ramp actually bugged and lacking in a trick zone?

Comment: Interesting. Is it one tile (with a '^' on it) or just the whole left side you think is bugged?

Comment: It's certainly the first two "tile"s, maybe even the third.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently it's you. I just played the track on Time Trial and hopped on the ramp on the left twice with a trick. The first time I jumped on the second tile (that's where the picture comes from) and the second time I jumped on the first one just to make sure, and I made a successful trick on both jumps.

[image]

**Edit:** Tried a third time, just to make sure:

[image]

**Edit 2:** You can never be too thorough with these experiments. Trying to be scientifically accurate, I tried to reproduce the jump under the same conditions: Yoshi, Pipe Frame car, Standard wheels (I think those are the ones you're using). The first time I was too slow since I stopped before the ramp to make sure I would go through the first tile and I didn't manage to make the jump. I thought you might have been on to something here, but the second time I went on with my normal speed and made the jump with a trick. I tried a third time and took a screenshot just to make sure, it works:

[image]

Comment: Yoshi is very happy to conclude your scientific experiment.

Comment: Indeed he is :)